# iptables not getting saved ? centos

Tags: centos, iptables

I am trying to save the iptables, when I run command

#service iptables save

it says [ok]

but when I again open the iptables the rules get revert to default.

Can anyone help me to understand this ??

Comment: Have you ever edited `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` by hand? What are the permissions of this file?

Comment: yes i did, I did not change the permissions

**-rw------- 1 root root 823 Apr  7 19:15 /etc/sysconfig/iptables**

what permisisions should i give ??

Comment: Could you please take a look at this discussion? - http://serverfault.com/questions/355096/iptables-not-persisting-after-reboot-on-centos-6-2

Comment: I did the same, my rules are seen in **iptables.save** but not in **/etc/sysconfig/iptables**

Comment: That's weird. Generally, `iptables.save` are the latest rules used before the last time you saved(somehow, like a backup). You file permissions seems to be fine too. I would suggest the workarround already explained on the discussion i linked while you try to find the root cause by reading bugfixes and updating packages. Save your rules using `iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables`